# how to show only a portion of an image on Hover as seen in the homepage of the site canva.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

Well, from my previous query I came to know that the guys is [canva.com](http://www.canva.com) have been playing with HTML5 canvas to produce the amazing effect on their homepage. Now my question is that, how can you make only a portion of the image(sharpened image, in case of the site here) appear when the mouse hovers. From what i know, the hover event handler would normally change the whole image on mousehover, but as seen on the site, the mouse hover only makes a portion(circular, to be precise) of the image to be displayed.

Can anyone explain how it can be done?

Thank You!

Comment: They have done it using canvas.

Comment: I understand they have done it using canvas, as i have already mentioned. Please read my question again!

Comment: This is commonly known as the "scratch off" effect.  It is done using canvas's `context.globalCompositeOperation`.  Here's a link to a tutorial: http://beej.us/blog/data/html5-canvas-globalcompositeoperation/  Check out the tutorial, experiment with coding it yourself and come back to Stackoverflow if you have more specific questions about your code.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: @markE Wow, I believe this is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you so much for the help. Will experiment on it.